# Why do I have a tiny Terminal logo blocking the minimize button in Terminal windows?

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-terminal, titlebar, window-buttons

Just as the title says, I have a mini icon when I open Terminal:

[image]

I would like to hide it if at all possible.

Comment: To _literally_ answer your question of "why": Because Ubuntu accidentally broke it with a custom patch that they applied last minute, during freeze period, thus not receiving proper testing; and unforturtunately don't care enough to fix it. For a practically more useful answer, see the other linked questions.